# How is config file of phpMyAdmin generated?

Tags: phpmyadmin

I followed a tutorial [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-lamp-amazon-linux-2.html) about installing phpMyAdmin on Amazon Linux. The step is basically downloading the whole package and extracting the sources to another directory. However, one thing that I don't quite understand is, how is the config file located at /etc/phpMyAdmin/config.inc.php and /etc/httpd/conf.d/phpMyAdmin.conf generated?

Comment: If you install PMA using the method in this link, neither of those files is "generated". What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: @fkraiem Hi, I am just trying to understand where do those files come from.

Comment: If you follow the instructions on the link, these files do not exist, so the question makes no sense. Why are you asking about these files?

Comment: @fkraiem Well, that's what I thought in the beginning. There's no way that those files are generated. So, I am confused in where did those file come from. Because it does exist after I install PMA after following the steps.

Comment: Wait, how is this question about Ubuntu, anyway? It uses `yum`, so that doesn't look like Ubuntu.